# How to connect aptana to local GIT repository

Tags: git, repository, aptana, local

My colleagues are working on some PHP project. They want use Git (by Git GUI) to synchronize, backup and store stable versions of our code. My boss wants to use for this purpose one computer, so it will became "Git server" with shared folder which contains actual repository.

All of developers use Aptana v3. Aptana has some tools to connect to repositories but I haven't experience, and I always get messages: "Fatal:...its not repository".
We won't use GitHub for that, too.

Q: How to connect Aptana on developers computers to that local Git repository without using GitHub or other services like it?

Thanks in advance.

Ask, if you want more info.

Kthaara

Answer (score 0):

First, on the server, choose a directory where you want to store the git repository and do :

```
git init --bare
```

This will initialize the git repository, the bare option tells to only keep trace of commits, and that's no need for local files.

And then on your computer's colleagues and on yours you have to configure a remote repository where every one will push their commits :

```
git remote add origin ssh://root@192.168.X.X/var/www/git/path
```

This means you have to connect the server using SSH. I don't think there other way if the server isn't local.

Comment: How to use this ssh for this? You mean, create private and public keys for it, sure, but how to connect them together? Repository is already created, I'm using Git GUI on Windows. Every computer has Windows.

Comment: Oh, I don't know much about SSH server for Windows, but it seams you can configure one quite simply : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/set-up-a-free-ssh-server-on-windows-7-with-freesshd/#.